# Installing speedbooster for magento errors

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to install http://guides.tinybrick.com/magento/speedbooster on a testserver.

When installing the pear package

```
[/home/USERNAME/public_html]# pear install /home/USERNAME/public_html/Speed_Booster-2.4.1.tgz
```

I get the following errors :

```
File "LICENSE.txt" in directory "<dir name="var">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "Observer.php" in directory "<dir name="Page">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "Observer.php" in directory "<dir name="Block">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "Page.php" in directory "<dir name="Model">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "Block.php" in directory "<dir name="Model">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "config.xml" in directory "<dir name="etc">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "Page.php" in directory "<dir name="Block">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "Block.php" in directory "<dir name="Block">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "LICENSE.txt" in directory "<dir name="var">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "Observer.php" in directory "<dir name="Product">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "Observer.php" in directory "<dir name="Category">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "config.xml" in directory "<dir name="etc">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "View.php" in directory "<dir name="Product">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "View.php" in directory "<dir name="Layer">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "View.php" in directory "<dir name="Category">" has invalid role "magecommunity", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "TinyBrick_FastCms.xml" in directory "<dir name="modules">" has invalid role "mageetc", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
File "TinyBrick_FastCatalog.xml" in directory "<dir name="modules">" has invalid role "mageetc", should be one of cfg, data, doc, php, script, test, www
Parsing of package.xml from file "/root/tmp/pear/cache/package.xml" failed
install failed
```

Could someone enlighten me on what is going wrong ?
Thank you!

EDIT :

Stupid me , I was installing the package from root.

```
./pear install /home/USERNAME/public_html/Speed_Booster-2.4.1.tgz
```

Is working...

Comment: Please post your solution as a real answer to help keeping the "Unanswered" list more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't read note from [official tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh#use_pear_to_download_and_install_magento_connect_extension):

> NOTE: in order to have properly functioning ./pear command, your
>   magento instance must be installed following one of the steps
>   explained at this page.